# how to show save data in the textbox

Tags: c#

```
    public JsonResult SaveTimeSheet(List<TaskHours> TaskHours,TimeSheet ID)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (TaskHours item in TaskHours)
            {
                if (TaskHours != null)
                {


                    string date = item.ID.Split(':')[1];
                    char[] arrDate = date.ToArray();
                    var dt = DateTime.Parse("" +
                        arrDate[0] + arrDate[1] + "/" +
                        arrDate[2] + arrDate[3] + "/" +
                        arrDate[4] + arrDate[5] + arrDate[6] + arrDate[7]);


                    //Save Timesheet
                    TimeSheet timeSheet = new TimeSheet();
                    var thisWeekStart = dt.AddDays(-(int)dt.DayOfWeek);
                    var thisWeekEnd = 
          thisWeekStart.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
                    timeSheet.StartDate = thisWeekStart;
                    timeSheet.EndDate = thisWeekEnd;

                       db.TimeSheets.Add(timeSheet);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        //Save Timehsheet data
                        TimeSheetData timesheetdata = new TimeSheetData();
                        timesheetdata.Date = dt;
                         string Hours = item.Value;
                        timesheetdata.Hours = Convert.ToDouble(Hours);
                        timesheetdata.TimeSheet = timeSheet;
                        string TaskID = item.ID.Split(':')[0];
                        timesheetdata.TaskID = Guid.Parse(TaskID);
                        db.TimesheetData.Add(timesheetdata);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                }

            }



            //Get Timesheet date               
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Message = "Task Hours has been 
      saved successfully" });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
      }           

    }
            }
      }
```

When i pass data into the textboxes, the data is easy to save but i 
want the saved data to be shown in a textbox. I want to retrieve the 
data from the database and show it in the textbox.

How do I check if timesheet exists for that week?
If it doesn't show a blank timesheet.
if it does exist then load that weeks data from the timesheet data table and pass it in json format to the view and then display the data.

How would this be done?

Comment: Can we please have a [mcve] instead of your whole app?

Comment: yeah sure i am editing my code.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it read better- however you still need to remove all irrelevant code so we can see what area you want assistance with.

Comment: Please continue reducing the code. There is way to much to take in. You also have 2 questions; "how to show save data in the textbox" and "How do I check if timesheet exists for that week?" Regarding the latter, check for null? I cannot say as it is not clear what you ask for. With this said... reducing the question to its core often makes you find the solution yourself. But until then: reduce, reduce, reduce.

Comment: I am already reduces the code.My question is how to show save data into the textboxes.